# Capturing incoming traffic to IPhone with Fiddler

Tags: iphone, request, fiddler, traffic

I am trying to capture all traffic from my app on Iphone. Now i can capture all outgoing traffic FROM my device, but nothing from incoming.
Here is instruction how i configured proxy in my fiddler and iphone: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForiOS

Is there some way to configure Fiddler to capture incoming requests or any another way to achieve this? It's desirable for application to decrypt HTTPS traffic as Fiddler do.

Comment: Charles Proxy and an iDevice can be setup to capture all traffic. There are instructions at the Charles Proxy site.

Comment: @zaph i tried to use Сharles, but it captured only outgoing requests too. Can you show me some link where i can find this instructions to capture incoming traffic?

Comment: Define what you mean by "incoming traffic"? The response to your request?

Comment: @zaph in particular case i have push notifications, what coming to application without any request from device. So, i want to capture this traffic exactly.

Comment: have you ever found a way to do this? I'm on the same boat, trying to see what is coming in a push notification

Answer (score 1):

APNS uses the following: ([Reference](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609))

- TCP port 5223 (used by devices to communicate to the APNs servers)
- TCP port 2195 (used to send notifications to the APNs)
- TCP port 2196 (used by the APNs feedback service)
- TCP Port 443 (used as a fallback on Wi-fi only, when devices are unable to communicate to APNs on port 5223)

The problem is that Fiddler, Charles Proxy and most programs like this capture only http/https protocol traffic. To capture all traffic including non http yo will need an analyzer such as Wire Shark.

Wire Shark is free but is not nearly as easy to use. It captures and displays all the packets including such as the TCP/IP level connection establishment. It also has one of the worse UI experiences ever, you will hate it. But it will capture all traffic in excruciating detail.